# Plotting in R in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, r, plot

I have a text file that I converted into a numeric vector:

```
numbers <- scan("list_of_numbers.txt")
```

I then put it into a table:

```
t <- table(numbers)
```

Which outputs like this:

```
  1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
621266 496647 436229 394595 353249 305882 253983 199455 147380 102872  67255 
12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22 
41934  24506  13778  7179   3646   1778   816    436    217    114    74 
23     24     25     26     27     28     29     30     31     32     33 
49     44     26     21     19     21     20     14      9     17     14 
34     35     36     37     38     39     40     41     42     43     44 
 7     11      9     14      3      5      8      4      4      2      3 
45     46     47     55     56     60     62     63     69     70     72 
 2      1      2      2      2      1      1      1      3      2      1 
78     82     85     93     95     114    125    265    331    350 
 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

How would I plot a line graph with x axis of numbers 1 - 25 and y axis the frequency values of the x axis all in the terminal window?

In addition, how can a plot like this (which is default saved as a .pdf file) be viewd in the linux terminal?

Most commands like less, cat, and xdg-open output a bunch of strange unreadable symbols.

Comment: I don't understand. what code are you using in the terminal from the start?

Comment: R does all of it's plotting in a graphics device. That typically means launching an X11 window on a linux box to see the plot. It does not render ascii plots to screen. You can write them to disc as a png or pdf. But you should know how to open those types of files. If not, you might get better results asking at http://superuser.com/. I can't tell if your question is really about R or not.

Comment: @MrFlick It sounds to me like they're on a linux server that might not have X11 capabilities so it outputs to pdf by default and there might not be an easy way for them to view the output.  But you are right - this sounds more like an issue for superuser.

Comment: `stem` might be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fbi](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida), the linux framebuffer imageviewer to open pdf files in the linux console.

A small problem can be that it needs root privileges. It seems like it can not run through R using `system`, it complains about not being a linux console. But you can use it in the terminal like:

```
sudo fbi Rplots.pdf
```

As for the plotting part of your question you can just use something like:

```
plot(t, xlim = c(1, 25))
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very convenient to use `txtplot::txtplot` as follow:

```
> cat("1 2 3 4 5 6", file = "list_of_numbers.txt", sep = "\n")
> numbers <- scan("list_of_numbers.txt")
Read 6 items
> t <- table(numbers)
> txtplot(t)
```

[image]

You can install it just by this command:

```
install.packages('txtplot')
```

I found that Jupyter may be the best wheel for us to handle that, and we can equip that following this tutorial: [Embed Graphs In Jupyter Notebooks in R](https://plotly.com/r/using-r-in-jupyter-notebooks/)

References:

1. [How To Install R on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04)
2. [scan](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/scan)